# DAO: Decide when to flush the changes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I've ran into an issue when using Exposed, I've decided to use DAO because they seem intuitive but I want to decide when to flush the changes and store them locally instead of flushing them everytime I set the value.
I need this because I need to store data about a player in and I want to update it only when he disconnects.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: If you have custom logic for when the DB actually needs to be updated, why don't you only access the DB once the player is actually disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer will be design related. I would make a separate class that has matching members, then have them convert to and from your DAO objects whenever you need database access. In this case, using Exposed Entities is still helpful to simplify references to foreign keys as well as simplifying update procedures.